# Rails - One-direction table association - accessing data issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have two models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :order_type
end

class OrderType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

my **schema.rb**:

```
create_table "order_types", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "ort_name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "ord_name"
  t.date     "ord_due_date"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "ordertype_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end

add_index "orders", ["ordertype_id"], name: "index_orders_on_ordertype_id"
add_index "orders", ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
```

There is only one-direction association between them. The `Order` model has a column "ordertype_id" that links to the appropriate `order_type`.

My question is, what is the best practice to access the `ort_name` value for each `@order` in a view.

Currently, I am using:

```
<p> 
  <strong>Ord type:</strong>
  <% OrderType.where(id:  @order.ordertype_id).each do |t| %>
  <%= t.ort_name %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

This solution results in many code repetitions. How I should change that? Can somebody advise, as I am not so experienced yet?

I tried this code, but it did not work:

```
@orders.order_type
```

Comment: what is the difference between `ord_name` and `ort_name`? It seems very bad practice to create a model for a single attribute...

Comment: Imagine such scenario: you have only 5 types of orders that can be picked up by a user while creating an order. But in the future you want to have an option to extend that list (for new orders). In my opinion it is correct to have a separate table that keeps available values of order types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems which you should address. It's ok to be a beginner, just take yourself time to learn and improve.

### Schema

First off, your schema is set up badly. If you want to limit the `order type` to certain values, you should do this with a validation.

```
class Order
  TYPES = %w[foo bar three four five]

  validates :order_type, inclusion: { in: TYPES }
end
```

This way, you can easily add values in the future, and remove the complexity of adding a new model and its relations.

### Column Names

Secondly, you should revise your column names. `ord_name` and `ord_due_date` is bad, it leads to ugly calls like `order.ord_name`. You should drop the prefix `ord`, it's superfluous.

Both steps would lead to this **schema.rb**

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.date     "due_date"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "order_type"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end
```

### Logic placement

My final advice is to never call queries from your view. Logic should always be in the controller / model & passed to the view via instance variables.

This is a big no no in rails:

```
<% OrderType.where(id:  @order.ordertype_id).each do |t| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

---

In the end, accessing the type is simply accomplished with:

```
@order.order_type
```

Comment: @Michal, I'd ask you to accept my answer, since you are [obviously using my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445865/rails-collection-select-populate-with-the-values-listed-in-a-model).

Answer (score -1):

Update your `Order` model to this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :order_type, foreign_key: 'ordertype_id`
end
```

then `order_type` should be easily accessible:

```
@order.order_type.ort_name
```

Comment: please update `Order` model. It should be working now

Comment: Yes. Now it is fine. Thank you :)

Comment: it's a horrible answer that ignores big problems of the OP code.

Comment: Then give us a good answer. @TheCha͢mp what's the problem with my code?

Comment: @TheCha͢mp I should admin it's great answer. Thanks for writing it.